# want 2 local machines to act as a client and server machine

Tags: php, apache, networking, virtual-machine

I have a windows virtual machine on my mac. I have apache web server on my mac. My virtual machine uses the same network as my mac so what I want to do is be able to access my mac webservice via my windows virtual machine.

This is because I want to test my application on IE. So my question is this...

How do I set up my windows virtual machine to call on mac webservice so my mac can handle the request.

Thanks

Comment: Browse to the Mac's IP in IE?

Comment: Yes, I want to make browser request to my mac IP via my virtual machine

Comment: If it's on the same network just find out what the Mac's IP is and type it into the address bar in IE... I don't see where the confusion is.

Comment: This question looks like SU material. It's all about checking if it's a NAT or a bridge connection in the VM.

Comment: I guess my confusion is if the MAC and the virtual machine share the same network. wouldn't they share the same ip ?? So how would I be able to reach out to the mac ?

Comment: I can't put my finger on what it is called. i guess it would be host name resolving. Where it looks for a particular domain name within the network before sending a request out to the web. let me know if I am making sense :P

Comment: Domain Name Resolving, and it won't matter if you just use the IP. DNS will only matter if you're using a hostname and not an IP.

Answer (score 0):

It's not necesary configuration on Windows virtual machine, the web service works over tcp/ip protocol and that it's supported by both (MAC and Windows).

**Attempts to call your webservice programmatically or directly from your browser on Windows.**

Comment: last time I had this setup, I was told I had to go edit the windows host file so windows will look locally for my localhost domain before calling out to the web. I want to call it through my web browser because I am trying to access a website I have located on the mac machine

Answer (score 0):

If you set up networking for the VM as NAT than they will have different IPs and you can connect to the mac. I'm not sure if you can do that in bridged.

Remember, mac doesn't equal IP.

Overall, I think you are over thinking it.